# Getting column name in Microsoft SQL Server (c#)

Tags: sql, sql-server, c#-3.0

I'm working in Visual Studios 2017 and I need to get the column names of a datatable  named "`Question`" , from a database named "`qst`". Is there any way, or command that can get me the column name and then insert it in `richTextBox1`?

Comment: You could run a query for column names from a table.

Comment: I tried it, but it seems it doesn't work. Can you exemplify ?

Comment: What have you tried? Can you give us an example, because we can't help if we don't know more. What kind of application do you build, which framework etc?

Comment: I used this 2 commands : "SELECT sys.columns FROM Question" and "SELECT c.name FROM Question" but didn't work. I work with .NET framework. My application is some sort of a game. There are questions and four answers, stored in the database. I want to get the column name in order to verify the answer. I want to check if the column  name is  "equal"(I now it's a string) with a value which is stored in a char[]array. (c[101]={'a','b','c','d','b','d'...}).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As variant you can use the following query to get all column names for a table

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME='YourTableName'
ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION
```

If it's necessary all table names you can get from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES`

```
SELECT *
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_TYPE='BASE TABLE'
```

Comment: yes, it works :> but i  have one more question.Is there any way to select the name of a specific column ?

Comment: Add the column name into the where clause of the first query.